# Selenium hover over dropdown label

Tags: c#, selenium, hover

I'm trying to do UI Automation with selenium. One simple task I have to do is hover over a dropdown element. I have tried using MoveToElement command it runs successfully with no errors but dropdown never opens during my automation run. For example purpose I have tried to run this on Macy's website. I have tried either of below these statements but had no luck.

```
Either this statement
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='showByDepartmentCaret']"))).Build().Perform();

Or
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='shopByDepartmentLabelText']"))).Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. You will need to click the drop down first to open the menu

though. So I am wondering if you question is really, How do I click on a drop down link?

```
        public static void HoverByXpath(string value)
    {
        var element = _wait.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.XPath(value)));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
    }
```

If I look at Macy's site, I would do something like this.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ID("showByDepartmentCaret")).Click();  

Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='mainNavigation']//a/span[text()='jewelry']")).Click();
```

This worked for me:

```
            Driver.Goto("https://www.macys.com/");
        Driver.FindElement(By.ID("shopByDepartmentLabelText")).Click();
        Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='mainNavigation']//a/span[text()='jewelry']")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is what I tried


WebDriverWait iwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

var element = iwait.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='showByDepartmentCaret']")));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();

It runs with no errors but does not perform any action

Comment: There is no action on there other than to hover.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second solution. The first statement clicks and navigates somewhere but not exactly on the dropdown label.  Where as the second statement fails because it is not able to find the given element

Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : Element is not displayed

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure why hover action doesn't work here. I don't see any dropdown during execution. And due to this the next statement for clicking any element on dropdown element fails.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I tried your last solution. It clicks somewhere on the page but still does not navigate where  it should. Also this click is performed from first statement. For next statement is gives element not found

Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='mainNavigation']//a/span[text()='jewelry']")).Click();

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. My display setting on laptop was not 100%. Browser was fine though.